# Aligning equations - I'm trying to write the equations and their names like this but I think I messed up somewhere

Tags: alignment

```
\begin{align}

&\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} & \text{Gauss’s Law}\\

&\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0 & \text{Gauss’s Law for Magnetism}

\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

. You've forgotten that n  alignment points requires 2n -1 ampersands: one to introduce each alignment column but the first, and one for each alignment point in its column. So try this:

```
\begin{align}    
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} & &\text{Gauss’ Law}\\
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} &= 0 & &\text{Gauss’ Law for Magnetism}    
\end{align}
```

Comment: Also, you can't have a blank line in an align environment.

Comment: @Teepeem: That's right. I mainly focused on the number of ampersands, so  I forgot this point. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 3):

A different approach using a simple enviroment `array` where I have used a different aesthetic of LaTeX-code. It is possible also to use also `alignat` instead of an `array`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lll}
\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{E} = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} &\qquad \text{Gauss's Law}\\
\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{0} &\qquad  \text{Gauss's Law for Magnetism} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]